# pip broken with this errer

Tags: python, pip

```
$ pip install selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I hope to install selenium to make crawling images, but this message makes me crazy. I can't googling this error as it is too long and I can't understand.

I tried to reinstall python with and pip with this code

```
$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
$ python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"
```

I just started to study programming. Plz let me know what is wrong.

Comment: thats using f strings formats which are python 3 syntax, you need to find an older version of selenium or even better, python 3

Comment: You specifically need python3.6+

Answer (score 0):

I just found what I did wrong.
I used `pip` instead `pip3`
With `pip3`, It works...
For someone in such a problem, I leave this post